# Apache common SimplexSolver LinearConstraint with OR condition

Tags: java, linear-programming

I use SimplexSolver to solve a linear problem from apache-commons: org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver

But I have a condition

```
x < 2 OR x > 10.
```

How can I use LinearConstraint with this condition? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do that with a continuous LP solver. You need MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) capabilities for this.

E.g.

```
 x <= 2 + 1000*b
 x >= 10 * b
 b in {0,1}
```

Comment: This can be formulated using a binary variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day.